# Extending Identity 2.2.1 to store custom data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

Currently in Identity 2.2.1, one can use User.Identity to retrieve user id and user name:

```
string ID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
string Name = User.Identity.Name;
```

However, I would like to extend this to User.Identity.FullName , User.Identity.FirstName ,etc.

I tried creating custom IIdentity and IPrincipal class and then setting FormAuthentication cookie. This I think is the wrong way to go as it then creates conflicts with DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie. http://problemfacing.blogspot.in/2013/07/aspnet-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or.html

There is also the claimsIdentity which can be looked into. I was unable to make it work for Identity 2.2.1 while there are plenty solutions for 2.0 and 2.1

Can someone tell me an elegant, simple way of achieving this with Identity 2.2.1?

Comment: Why don't you extend `IIdentity`? then you can use it this way: `User.Identity.FirstName()`

Comment: I tried that following this link: http://problemfacing.blogspot.in/2013/07/aspnet-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or.html However, then there is a conflict between FormsAuthentication cookie and DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie

Answer (score 1):

You can add those properties as `Claims` in your `ApplicationUser` like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var identity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        var user = this;
        // Add Full Name, Firstname etc....
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName));
    }
}
```

Then you can access those claims without having to make a trip to the database.

If you wish to extend your User class then you can create extension methods for Identity or for Principal. Here's one example:

```
public class UserPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        : base(principal)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Full Name of current logged in user.
    /// </summary>
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FindFirst("FullName").Value ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can create a method in your controller to access FullName (like this):

```
    private UserPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new UserPrincipal(base.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }
```

Now you can use `CurrentUser.FullName` in your controller.

In case you want to abstract this, you can create a BaseController class:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public UserPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new UserPrincipal(base.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }
}
```

and inherit from `BaseController` instead of `Controller` in all your controllers.

Comment: Will soon try this out. Currently, I made a cookie and stored this information separately.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to create custom user for Identity.

First step is to create the `User` which will hold your custom fields and derive it from `IdentityUser` in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` namespace:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to create your custom `UserManager` by deriving from Identity's `UserManager`

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<MyUser>
{
    public UserManager(Context context, IUserTokenProvider<MyUser, string> tokenProvider = null)
        : base(new MyUserStore(context))
    {
        UserTokenProvider = tokenProvider;

        UserValidator = new UserValidator<MyUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
            RequiredLength = 2
        };
    }
}
```

And finally you should create a custom `UserStore` by deriving from the default one:

```
public class MyUserStore : UserStore<MyUser>
{
    public MyUserStore(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error while creating MyUserStore. -> saying UserStore must have a return type. Moreover, I am using int as primary key instead of string

Comment: Can you post a more detailed error message? Why ca't you use strings? I'm afraid that to use `int` you would have to override half of the Identity as everything there is based on strings

Comment: I already have it working with INT as primary key. I followed this article to achieve that http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity 

I have created a photo with all the errors I am facing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hcg9ork34s4txy0/i.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You should replace `Context` with you own class that derives from `DbContext`and also rename the constructor from `UserStore` to `MyUserStore` I'll update the answer

Comment: Ok now one issue remains: UserTokenProvider takes string instead of Int for primary key.

Comment: I think you need to implement your own `UserTokenProvider`, I can't be of help here as I haven't done that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87246/discussion-between-shyamal-parikh-and-vsevolod-goloviznin).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding extension method:

```
public static class IdentityExtention
{
   public static string FullName(this System.Security.Principal.IIdentity user)
   {
            return // return fullName from database;
   }
}
```

Then you can easily use that in your views:

```
User.Identity.FullName()
```

Comment: But this would execute database query every time it is accessed right?!